# AutoMapper - Conditional Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, automapper

I've looked around and couldn't quite find the answer to my question. What I'm looking to do is conditional map the destination object (not field/property, object). In other words, something like this:

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Flag {get; set;}
}
public class Destination
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

var sources = new List<Source> 
                  { 
                      new Source{Flag = "V", Id = 1},
                      new Source{Flag = "B", Id = 2} 
                  };

var destinations = Mapper.Map<List<Source>, List<Destination>>(sources);

destinations.Count.ShouldEqual(1);
destinations[0].Id.ShouldEqual(2);
```

Does anyone know how to configure the type mapping? I'm looking for something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .SkipIf(src => src.Flag != "B");
```

I just don't see anything in the configuration options that seems to support this. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK currently there is nothing built-in allowing you to achieve this. You could do the following though:

```
var destinations = Mapper.Map<List<Source>, List<Destination>>(
    sources.Where(source => source.Flag == "B")
);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not great as you effectively end up doing the mapping yourself....but its ok for exceptional cases and allows the mapping logic to be contained internally....

```
 config.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .AfterMap((source, dest) =>
            {
                 if (source.Flag == "B")
                 {
                     //do stuff
                 }
            });
```